# Windows: Determine domain name from cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, active-directory

If I don't know if computer is in domain or not, and I don't know the workstations name, Is it possible to determine if the user(for example `jack` which is not the user I'm logged in) is domain username or local username from command line? I've searched to find the answer but all I got is to check the `USERDOMAIN` variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic useraccount get localaccount,name
```

or to be specific to a certain user:

```
wmic useraccount where "name='Gast'" get localaccount
```

To get it into a variable:

```
for /f %%a in ('wmic useraccount where "name='Gast'" get localaccount /value^|find "="') do set %%a
echo %localaccount%
```

(Note: this is syntax for batchfile. If you want to execute on command line, replace every `%%a` with `%a`)

Comment: thank you :) but How can I check if user is in domain?

Comment: don't have a Domain here, but I'd expect `LocalAccount` to be `FALSE`, when the user is in a domain.

Comment: It says `No instance available` when I provide AD user, It does the same if I provide user whihc doesn't exist, is there any reliable way to do this? I tried this command `wmic useraccount where "name='Gast'" get localaccount`

Comment: I don't think, you have a user named `Gast` (unless you are german too). Does `wmic useraccount get localaccount,name /value` help?

Comment: I've changed `Gast` to proper username, I executed that command too but it gives all the local usernames and `LOCALACCOUNT=TRUE`